# Random file generator code?

Tags: random

Does anyone have a simple shell script or c program to generate random files of a set size
with random content under linux?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How about:

```
head -c SIZE /dev/random > file
```

Comment: If you can sacrifice some entropy you can also use /dev/urandom instead. It will be faster since it will not block waiting for more environmental noise to occur

Comment: Good suggestion.  Yes it doesn't need to be perfectly random at all.

Comment: If you somehow find yourself needing to read from /dev/random and it's blocking due to lack of sufficient randomness one reasonable way to get some more is to run a 'du /'. This gets the disk moving and generated some extra entropy (not guaranteed for flash drives).

Comment: When I run `head -c 1024 /dev/random > file`, it seems like  it was waiting something to complete and never finish writing to my file, what may be the problem?

Comment: @Satoru Logic Read what myself and @paulrubel wrote in the comments above

Answer (score 4):

`openssl rand` can be used to generate random bytes.
The command is below:

`openssl rand [bytes] -out [filename]`

For example,`openssl rand 2048 -out aaa` will generate a file named `aaa` containing 2048 random bytes.

Comment: For some versions of OpenSSL you may need `openssl rand -out <filename> <bytes>`.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few ways:

Python:

```
RandomData = file("/dev/urandom", "rb").read(1024)
file("random.txt").write(RandomData)
```

Bash:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=myrandom.txt bs=1024 count=1
```

using C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int byte_count = 1024;
    char data[4048];
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("/dev/urandom", "rb");
    fread(&data, 1, byte_count, fp);
    int n;

    FILE *rand;
    rand=fopen("test.txt", "w");
    fprintf(rand, data);
    fclose(rand);
    fclose(rand);
}
```

Comment: I don't think that C code is valid. You'll get a coredump if you try to run it.

Answer (score 0):

Python.  Call it `make_random.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import random
import sys
import string
size = int(sys.argv[1])
for i in xrange(size):
    sys.stdout.write( random.choice(string.printable) )
```

Use it like this

```
./make_random 1024 >some_file
```

That will write 1024 bytes to stdout, which you can capture into a file.  Depending on your system's encoding this will probably not be readable as Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick an dirty script I wrote in Perl. It allows you to control the range of characters that will be in the generated file.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

if ($#ARGV < 1) { die("usage: <size_in_bytes> <file_name>\n"); }

open(FILE,">" . $ARGV[0]) or die "Can't open file for writing\n";

# you can control the range of characters here
my $minimum = 32;
my $range = 96;

for ($i=0; $i< $ARGV[1]; $i++) {
    print FILE chr(int(rand($range)) + $minimum);
}

close(FILE);
```

To use:

```
./script.pl file 2048
```

---

Here's a shorter version, based on S. Lott's idea of outputting to STDOUT:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# you can control the range of characters here
my $minimum = 32;
my $range = 96;

for ($i=0; $i< $ARGV[0]; $i++) {
    print chr(int(rand($range)) + $minimum);
}
```

*Warning:* This is the first script I wrote in Perl. Ever.  But it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my [generate_random_file.py](https://bitbucket.org/rsnitsch/filehasher/src/205f2bf55b27d53aa3970592a8ffb12c11a6fc30/testdata/generate_random_file.py) script (Python 3) that I used to generate test data in a project of mine.

- It works both on Linux and Windows.
- It is very fast, because it uses [`os.urandom()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.urandom) to generate the random data in chunks of 256 KiB instead of generating and writing each byte separately.