# Is there a more efficient way to generate a random file in Perl?

Tags: perl, file-io, random

This is my first Perl script. Ever:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

if ($#ARGV < 1) { die("usage: <size_in_bytes> <file_name>\n"); }

open(FILE,">" . $ARGV[0]) or die "Can't open file for writing\n";

# you can control the range of characters here
my $minimum = 32;
my $range = 96;

for ($i=0; $i< $ARGV[1]; $i++) {
    print FILE chr(int(rand($range)) + $minimum);
}

close(FILE);
```

Its purpose is to [generate a file in a specified size filled with random characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445045/random-file-generator-code/3445156#3445156).

It works but it is pretty slow. It takes a few seconds to write a 10MB random file.
Does anyone have suggestions/tips on how to make it faster/better? Also feel free to point out common newbie mistakes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. You could ask `rand` to create more than one value for you each time you call it.
2. Collect several characters together before calling `print`. Printing one character at a time is inefficient.

```
for (my $bytes = 0; $bytes < $num_bytes; $bytes += 4) {
    my $rand = int(rand($range ** 4));
    my $string = '';
    for (1..4) {
        $string .= chr($rand % $range + $minimum);
        $rand = int($rand / $range);
    }
    print FILE $string;
}
```

Comment: I *think* perl works best in 4k chunks sent to the stream. Related SO to changing the stream buffer size: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251062/how-can-i-set-the-file-read-buffer-size-in-perl-to-optimize-it-for-large-files

Comment: Why do you use `my $rand = int(rand($range ** 4))` and `chr($rand % $range + $minimum)` instead of just `my $rand = int(rand($range)` and `chr($rand + $minimum)` ?

Comment: `rand($range**4)` contains enough information to generate 4 random characters

Comment: but isn't `rand($range)` also fits that criteria?

Answer (score 1):

If you need random numbers from a range, I'm not aware of more efficient way. Your script adjusted to my likings:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

die("usage: $0 <size_in_bytes> <file_name>\n") unless @ARGV == 2;

my ($num_bytes, $fname) = @ARGV;

open(FILE, ">", $fname) or die "Can't open $fname for writing ($!)";

my $minimum = 32;
my $range = 96;

for (1 .. $num_bytes) {
    print FILE pack( "c", int(rand($range)) + $minimum);
}

close(FILE);
```

I use `pack("c")` when I really need binary. `chr()` might be fine too but IIRC it actually depends on what the character encoding your environment is using (think ASCII vs. utf8.)

BTW if you really need binary file for Windows compatibility you might want to add `binmode FILE;` after the `open`.

Otherwise, if range is optional, you can simply `dd if=/dev/random of=$filename bs=1 count=$size_of_the_output` (or on Linux the faster crypto-unsafe `/dev/urandom`). But that would be much slower as `/dev/random` really tries to deliver real random bits - as they become available. And if there is not enough of them (e.g. your platform doesn't have H/W RNG) then performance would really suffer - compared to the blazingly fast libc's pseudo-random number generator (the Perl uses internally to implement the `rand()`).